# How to add wordpress customize section in custom post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

How can I create that option please see [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLw0F.png)
on my custom theme?
I can make the theme using a custom post but I want to make website similar to this image.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The items shown in the image are 'Customizer Sections' and are added via the customizer API. You would use some code like this to add a section. *Note: You would also need to add settings and controls.*

```
<?php
function mytheme_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
    //All our sections, settings, and controls will be added here
    $wp_customize->add_section( 'mytheme_new_section_slider' , array(
        'title'      => __( 'Slider Settings', 'mytheme' ),
        'priority'   => 30,
    ) );
    // you would also have settings and controls that are added to the section.
    // if you add a section and it contains no controls it will not appear.
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'mytheme_customize_register' );
```

Here's some documentation about the `add_section` method: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/add_section

And some about the overall process, including adding settings and controls: https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API